# Multiple SMTP Sessions on the Same Server

Tags: email, ssl, routes, smtp

Can you have 2 SMTP sessions on the same server. 1 for TLS routing, and one without?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any problem opening several connections to the same SMTP server. 
There are legitimate situations when this may happen. For example, when several machines behind a [NAT router](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) open a connection, these connections appear to be coming from the same IP.

However, if you try to open many more connections, you will hit the server incoming connections limit, which restricts the number of connections coming from the same IP address in order to prevent DOS attacks.